# Django/Python HTML recommend friends

Tags: python, html, django

So I'm trying to recommend users for a social network based on this condition: If A follows B and B follows C then, we should recommend that A follows C.

I have this code so far which displays mutual friends, all users and those that follow you

```
<ul>
{% for member in members %}
    <li> <a href="?view={{ member.username }}"> {{ member.username }} </a>
    {% if member in following %}
        {% if member in followers %}
            &harr; is a mutual friend [<a href="?remove={{ member.username }}">drop</a>] </li>  
        {% else %}
            &larr; you are following [<a href="?remove={{ member.username }}">drop</a>] </li>   
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        {% if member in followers %}
            &rarr; is following you [<a href="?add={{ member.username }}">recip</a>] </li>
        {% else %}
            [<a href="?add={{ member.username }}">follow</a>] </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But I'm stuck on doing this condition so any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Django templates should not encapsulate overly complex logic, by design. They are mainly a design tool, and the main logic should run in python. This is why there are clear limits what you can do in a template without too much hoops.

Here is an simple option, how to implement your requirements

```
def get_status(user,member):

     ... calculate follower status here ...
     return msg,href,link_text
```

In the view, where you run your queryset:

```
members = Members.objects.all()
for member in members:
    member.msg,member.href,member.link_text = get_status(member,request.user)
```

Finally, in the template:

```
<ul>
{% for member in members %}
    <li> <a href="?view={{ member.username }}"> {{ member.username }} </a>
        &harr; {{ member.msg  }} [<a href="{{ member.href }}">{{ member.link_text }}</a>] </li>  
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Note: this is a simple answer. You should really think through this logic, where you want to put it (in the model maybe, as Member method), use reverse for urls etc. But the idea is not to put basic app rules in the template

Comment: Thanks. So within the get_status() function is where I do my logic, essentially checking that user follows member and member follows C and then recommend C to user?

Comment: Yes. This is really basic, you probably want one function to return a generic "status", and other lang function to pull the correct msg, href etc. Consider to add a helpers.py with such functions in the app directory.